# Tensorflow resize_image_with_crop_or_pad

Tags: python, tensorflow

I want to call `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(images,height,width)` to resize my input images. As my input images are all in form as 2-d numpy array of pixels, while the image input of `resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` must be 3-d or 4-d tensor, it will cause an error. What should I do?

Comment: Use `reshape` in order to turn your 2D array in a 3 or 4D array with 3rd/4th dimension equal to 1. Suppose your image is stored in te variable `image`, this should make your program work:                                                
`image = image[..., np.newaxis]`. Basically you need to add the number of channels.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's suppose that you got `images` that's a `[n, W, H]` numpy nd-array, in which `n` is the number of images and `W` and `H` are the `width` and the `height` of the images.

1. Convert images to a tensor, in order to be able to use tensorflow functions:

   `tf_images = tf.constant(images)`
2. Convert `tf_images` to the image data format used by tensorflow (thus from `n, W, H` to `n, H, W`)

   `tf_images = tf.transpose(tf_images, perm=[0,2,1])`
3. In tensorflow, every image has a depth channell, thus altough you're using grayscale images, we have to add the `depth=1` channell.

   `tf_images = tf.expand_dims(tf_images, 2)`
4. Now you can use `tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad` to resize the batch (that how has a shape of `[n, H, W, 1]` (4-d tensor)):

   `resized = tf.image.resize_image_with_crop_or_pad(tf_images,height,width)`